# Mule Dataweave Replace Null with Specific Value

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

My request payload looks something like below:

```
{
    "AllCodes": [
        {
            "Code1": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "Code2": "TUV"
        },
        {
            "Code3": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a function which will replace the values in the above with a certain value. The code that I've now is below:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%function LookUp(codes) codes mapObject {($$): $.code} //function to return string values for above codes
%var codeLookup = LookUp(sessionVars.OutputCodes)
%var FinalCodes = payload.AllCodes map codeLookup[$] joinBy ';' 
--
FinalCodes
```

The output of sessionVars.OutputCodes is:

```
{
  "CodeMaster": {
    "PrimaryCodes": {
      "PrimarySpecCodes": {
        "ABC": {
          "code": "ABC-String1"
        },
        "TUV": {
          "code": "TUV-String2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output that I am expecting is:

```
"ABC-String1;XYZ-String2;XYZ"
```

As you can see above, since the function is returning the values for only "ABC" and "TUV" codes, my final output should have the original value if no function value found.

I was trying to use a default value before map operator. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what does sessionVars.OutputCodes look like?

Comment: It looks,
{
    "CodeMaster": {
        "PrimaryCodes": {
            "PrimarySpecCodes": {
                "ABC": {"code": "ABC-String1"},
                "TUV": {"code": "TUV-String2"}
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get all the values for `allCodes` with `$ pluck $`, then if `codes[$]` is not found, we default to the value `$`. I believe you just need to add `default $` to your original dataweave for it to work, but I gave a complete solution for other users on StackOverflow.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var outputCodes = 
{
    "CodeMaster": {
        "PrimaryCodes": {
            "PrimarySpecCodes": {
                "ABC": {
                    "code": "ABC-String1"
                },
                "TUV": {
                    "code": "TUV-String2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

%var allCodes = 
{
    "AllCodes": [
        {
            "Code1": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "Code2": "TUV"
        },
        {
            "Code3": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
%var codes = outputCodes.CodeMaster.PrimaryCodes.PrimarySpecCodes mapObject {
    ($$): $.code
}

---
(flatten (allCodes.AllCodes map ($ pluck $))) map (
    codes[$] default $
) joinBy ';'
```

this produces:

```
"ABC-String1;TUV-String2;XYZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to solve this. One could be as follows:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var payload2= { "CodeMaster": { "PrimaryCodes": { "PrimarySpecCodes": { "ABC": {"code": "ABC-String1"}, "TUV": {"code": "TUV-String2"} } } } }

%var codes =  payload2.CodeMaster.PrimaryCodes.PrimarySpecCodes mapObject {
    ($$) : $.code
}
%var finalCodes = (payload.AllCodes map {
    a: $  mapObject {
          a1: codes[$] default $
     }
}.a.a1) joinBy ";"
---
finalCodes
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please let me know what "temp" would do? If the function doesn't find any corresponding values for payload codes, the codes in the payload should be in the final string. Else, it should be the function returned values joined by ";"

Comment: temp is just a placeholder for something empty as then i can use the "-" operator to remove all empty aka temp from the final array before i joinBy ";"

Comment: Since initially i didn't see XYZ at the end of the string i had scripted it accordingly. In case you need XYZ at the end , you can replace temp with $ in the default and remove "- temp" from the script.